# Displaying all the columns from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

How to display all the columns of two different tables as ONE ?

I have two tables, movies and movie_actors in MovieDB. The id of the movies is primary key and `id` of the `movie_actor` is foreign key, and `movies_actor.id` is referenced to movies.id

```
   TABLE MOVIES
   id/title/director/genre/year_of_release

   TABLE MOVIE_ACTOR
   id/title/actor/age
```

I used Union, but its not working, because union is asking for same number of attributes. but here the first table has 4 columns and the second has only 3.

I would like to display as in one table

```
   id/title/director/genre/year_of_release/actor/age
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use a join on the tables.  The join will be between the two fields that are primary/foreign keys to each other which you stated was the `id` in the `movie` table and the `id` in the `movie_actor` table:

```
select m.id,
  a.title,
  m.director,
  m.genre,
  m.year_of_release,
  a.actor,
  a.age
from movies m
inner join movie_actor a
  on m.id = a.id
```

If you are not familiar with join syntax than here is great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

An `INNER JOIN` will return the set of records that match in both tables. If you had records in the `movie` table that did not have matching records in the `move_actor` table, then you would want to use a `LEFT JOIN`. This would return all movies even if it did not have records in the `movie_actor` table:

```
select m.id,
  a.title,
  m.director,
  m.genre,
  m.year_of_release,
  a.actor,
  a.age
from movies m
left join movie_actor a
  on m.id = a.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bfc7/2) of both queries.

Comment: If there is not a matching row in a `LEFT JOIN` then it will display a null.

Answer (score 1):

You can join these tables using the following query.

```
SELECT MOVIES.id, title, director, genre, year_of_release, actor, age
    FROM MOVIES INNER JOIN MOVIE_ACTOR ON (MOVIE.id = MOVIE_ACTOR.id)
```